# Como habilitar CORS para acesso de página web de um domínio diferente, no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cors

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que esta se comunicando com o Checkout do Pag Seguro através da url Web Server https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br que esta funcionando perfeitamente, após a realização do pagamento o PagSeguro fornece a possibilidade de indicar uma página em minha aplicação para receber o status da transação.

Só que estou desenvolvendo em localhost e o endereço gerado pelo IIS não é um endereço válido para o Sandbox do PagSeguro http://localhost:12345/

Na documentação do Pagseguro pede para utilizar o recurso CORS abaixo

**Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br");**

A pergunta como e onde insiro no código de minha aplicação esta configuração **Response.AppendHeader** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso você deve instalar um pacote de extensão que faz esse tratamento do CORS.

No console do NUGET digite o seguinte comando:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Em seu arquivo WebApiConfig coloque o código `config.EnableCors();` :

```
 public static class WebApiConfig 
    { 
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) 
        { 
            // Configurando o CORS
            config.EnableCors(); 


            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); 

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
                name: "DefaultApi", 
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
            ); 
        } 
    }
```

Em sua controller coloque o seguinte atributo:

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

ou para futuras chamadas, considerando chamadas de todas origens:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Comment: Realizei todos os procedimentos acima citado e coloquei também no PagSeguro a URL de retorno da minha aplicação " http://localhost/Anuncios/RetornoPagamento " e não funciona, o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Inserir a linha EnableCors aqui ... [EnableCors(origins: "https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class AnunciosController : Controller{   ...   }

Comment: O erro persiste como "cross-origin"?